# Prevent frame view with GoDaddy forward (301 with mask)

Tags: domains, dns, godaddy, domain-forwarding

I have a domain name at GoDaddy and have forwarded it to an external domain, using the settings 301 with mask.

However, when I go to my GoDaddy domain and press view source code then I only get that the page is embedded in a frame. Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>TITLE HERE</title>
  <META name="description" content="DESCRIPTION HERE"><META name="keywords" content="KEYWORDS HERE">
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="MYGODADDYDOMAIN.COM" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 04 -->
<!-- -->
</html>
```

How can I prevent this and get a normal redirect?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting `forward with mask` you need to select `forwarding only`. Putting it inside a frame is how they mask the domain the site is on.

Comment: Except with forward only the title will show the IP address.
So, instead of placing it in a frame it will be displayed.

Comment: With forward only, they simply provide HTTP headers and no HTML is specified by GoDaddy. In this instance the browser title should be specified by the <title>Your title here</title> in the head section of your HTML, otherwise the browser may determine its own title based on the host part of the URL and this can vary between different browser vendors.